# IMPORTXML failing for certain link, but succeeding for another one with just a different ticker

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am pulling the Zack's score using IMPORTXML. The following is working:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(IMPORTXML("https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/"&TO_TEXT(A1), "//*[@class='rank_view']/text()[1]")),"")
```

This works when A1 cell is ticker AAP and returns '3-Hold'.

This fails when A1 cell is ticker AAPL.

The code doesn't change, just works for certain tickers but not for others.

Comment: When I tested `APPL` in the cell "A1" using your formula, `2-Buy` is returned. Is this the result you expect?

Comment: Yes, correct. That's the expectation. Maybe its possible that there is some issue because of Adblock or some other extension in the browser.

Answer (score -2):

Test it ...

=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/" & G2; "//*[@class='rank_view']/text()[1]");1)